# How do I print separate items from list in Python?

Tags: python, list

for example I have a list

```
data=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 3, 6, 5]]
```

I want to print numbers 1, 3, 4 from the first array of data
I can't find how can i print it
My code so far

```
print(data[0][0:4])
```

how can I make it not to print 2 (I'm using python 3.2)??

Comment: Side note: switch to python 3.3 or 3.4

Comment: what is the logic behind omitting the values ? I mean what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [288]: data=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 3, 6, 5]]

In [289]: for i in [0,2,3]:
   .....:     print(data[0][i], end=' ')
   .....:     
1 3 4
```

Comment: You probably want an extra `print()` at the end. But otherwise, very nice way to show this without any novice-unfriendly simplifications.

Answer (score 2):

```
print([data[0][0]] + data[0][2:4])
```

Comment: This will give a `TypeError`; you're concatenating a list with an integer.

Comment: I forgot the brackets around `data[0][0]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to print everything from `data[0][0:4]` that isn't the number `2`, you can do this:

```
print([x for x in data[0][0:4] if x != 2])
```

This can be extended to, e.g., not print even numbers:

```
print([x for x in data[0][0:4] if x % 2 != 0])
```

---

If you want to "slice around" whatever's in `data[0][1]`, you can just concatenate the two slices around it:

```
print(data[0][0:1] + data[0][2:4])
```

This can also be extended to, e.g., remove the whole slice from `[1:3]` instead of just `[1:2]`:

```
print(data[0][0:1] + data[0][3:4])
```

Although it doesn't work as well for removing discontiguous groups (like whatever's in index 1, 3, or 8); for that, you'd probably want `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore certain indexes, you could use `enumerate`:

```
" ".join([str(i) for ind,i in enumerate(data[0][0:4]) if ind != 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> data=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,4,3,6,5]]
>>> m=pe.sheets.MultipleFilterableSheet(data)
>>> # get rid of other columns
>>> m.filter(pe.filters.ColumnFilter([1,4,5,6]))
>>> print(pe.utils.to_array(m))
[[1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 6]]
>>> print m.row[0]
[1, 3, 4]
>>> print m.row[0][0:3]
[1, 3, 4]
```